# Dropbear - cannot SSH when user's shell is redirected

Tags: linux, dropbear

I am running Linux on an embedded system with Buildroot+Dropbear.  I am using systemd for init, if that matters.

Logging in via SSH works properly for root, but not as a regular user (gives "Permission denied, please try again.").  The user's shell is redirected to a custom program with this entry in /etc/passwd:

```
admin:x:1000:1000:Custom user:/home/admin:/opt/customCLI
```

Logging in as the `admin` user works fine when the shell is `/bin/sh`.  `/opt/customCLI` is a program I wrote that accepts a minimal set of commands.

Is there a way to support SSH logins directly to a custom program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your program to `/etc/shells`

Some login tools will reject logins to users with unknown shells. This prevents the back door of using SSH to modify files or forward ports while being locked out with  `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`.